# Using native lock screen android in my application

Tags: android, locking, screen, native

I want execute native lock screen when my android application start. If the user put correct password the application keep running, but it is mistake, the application finish.

Anybody know how I do this ?

Thank´s

Comment: Did you tried 'DevicePolicyManager' or 'KeyGuardManager'? Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724428/how-can-i-set-up-screen-lock-with-a-password-programmatically in another context. Use it in your case

Answer (score 0):

so far I know that you will need to work on your manifest file for  your applications' wake screen state.. just play with your manifest file, you will find it.

Comment: The manifest is only parameter file. I think that is necessary execute the command in program to call lock screen in the point that I need. Anybody have a example this ?