# Lock android tablet when wifi is not in range

Tags: android, tablet

My tablets are going to be used in public places and i want to avoid theft without chaining the tablet to the table.

One of ideas i came up with is to lock the tablet when it is out of certain wi-fi range, so tablet comes unusable for thief.

The lock should also apply after reboot.

If possible, then probably this lock wouldn't survive reinstalling, but that's fine.

I know that this idea has flaws, but i just want to know is it even possible?

Perhaps a system service that runs on boot?

Comment: may be a system service that euns on boot and which have administrator privilages and also which listens to WiFi changes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13824002/2910492) for an example of how to set the lock.

What you can do is call that once a wifi goes out of reach, and remove it again once the wifi is near.