# Set lockscreen to "None" programmatically?

Tags: java, android, lockscreen

I have the requirement to disable the lock screen and set the lock screen type to "None". My device is rooted (can run with SU permission) + can run as a system application with system permissions (under /system/app).

I have tried a few things to no avail.

**Try 1**

This seems to be deprecated and not working.

```
KeyguardManager manager = (KeyguardManager) this.getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = manager.newKeyguardLock("abc");
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

**Try 2**

This didn't work either.

1. Mount system partition as writable
2. Edit `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db`
3. Execute the following SQL.

   `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO system (name, value) VALUES ('lockscreen.disabled', '1');`
   `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO secure (name, value) VALUES ('lockscreen.disabled', '1');`

**Try 3**

Rebooted the machine but still no luck.

```
android.provider.Settings.Secure.putLong(mContentResolver, Settings.Secure.LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED, false);`
android.provider.Settings.Secure.putLong(mContentResolver, "lockscreen.password_type", DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_SOMETHING);`
android.provider.Settings.Secure.putLong(mContentResolver, "lockscreen.password_type_alternate", DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_UNSPECIFIED);
android.provider.Settings.Secure.putLong(mContentResolver, "lockscreen.disabled", true);
```

Is there anything else that I can try?

Please note that **I do not want to disable the keyguard only when application is running.**

Comment: Which android version?

Comment: I am running on Android 4.1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724428/how-can-i-set-up-screen-lock-with-a-password-programmatically - hope this helps

Comment: I would like to hear from your progress. Any solution so far?

Comment: @RanhiruCooray reached anything ?

Answer (score 15):

You can try this:

```
adb shell sqlite3 /data/system/locksettings.db "UPDATE locksettings SET value = '1' WHERE name = 'lockscreen.disabled'"

adb shell sqlite3 /data/system/locksettings.db "UPDATE locksettings SET value = '0' WHERE name = 'lockscreen.password_type'"

adb shell sqlite3 /data/system/locksettings.db "UPDATE locksettings SET value = '0' WHERE name = 'lockscreen.password_type_alternate'"
```

It works on my rooted Nexus 4.

Comment: Running the 1st command and then rebooting the phone worked for me.

Comment: Related source code: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/3f453164ec884d26a556477027b430cb22a9b7e3/services/core/java/com/android/server/LockSettingsStorage.java

Comment: For `/data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db` it is said that it's best to use `adb shell settings put secure lockscreen.disabled 1` to modify the database. Is there a similar utility to modify `locksettings.db` instead of direct sqlite call?

Comment: @farmir One can `adb pull` those files, as detailed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1r2zha/how_i_managed_to_use_my_android_device_with_a).

Comment: This can be done easier with `locksettings` command: `adb shell locksettings set-disabled true`

Answer (score 4):

After searching a little bit in the android [source](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/) i stick now within a function called [`onPreferenceTreeClick`](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/ChooseLockGeneric.java#107) from the class `ChooseLockGeneric` which seems to be called when the unlock method is chosen (in the preferences).

In that method [`updateUnlockMethodAndFinish`](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/ChooseLockGeneric.java#updateUnlockMethodAndFinish) is called which sets the unlock method. So maybe calling `updateUnlockMethodAndFinish(DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_UNSPECIFIED,true);` could be exactly what you want.

I don't know whether this fit your needs and don't know whether this works (maybe there are any visibility problems or security mechanisms). I am just speculating.

EDIT:
This could help also: [`startFragment(this,"com.android.settings.ChooseLockGeneric$ChooseLockGenericFragment",SET_OR_CHANGE_LOCK_METHOD_REQUEST, null);`](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/SecuritySettings.java#372)

Answer (score 3):

use `adb shell locksettings clear --old xxxx` to instantly remove the lockscreen lock (even when the phone is in locked state)
`xxxx` is the pattern number, refer below image.
Example: `locksettings clear --old 1236`

To again set the pattern use: `locksettings set-pattern 1236`

[image]

---

usage:

```
   locksettings set-pattern [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL] NEW_PATTERN
   locksettings set-pin [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL] NEW_PIN
   locksettings set-password [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL] NEW_PASSWORD
   locksettings clear [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL]
   locksettings verify [--old OLD_CREDENTIAL]
   locksettings set-disabled DISABLED
   locksettings get-disabled
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a late answer, but you can try command line "locksettings set-disabled true".
It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2):

you have to declare this uses-permission on AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

And in your code:

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Lock");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

when your application is destroyed or paused to release this lock using below:

```
wakeLock.release();
```

I suggested to call the **acquire** inside the **onResume()** of your activity and the **release** in **onPause()**.

Comment: Thanks but this is ONLY when the application is running. This doesn't disable the lock screen of the device.

Answer (score 2):

I tried modifying /data/system/locksettings.db as was suggested by @ByteHamster, with no luck.

> ```
> adb shell sqlite3 /data/system/locksettings.db "UPDATE locksettings SET value = '1' WHERE name = 'lockscreen.disabled'"
> ```

I then renamed the `locksettings.db` to `locksettings.db.old` and rebooted.  The lockscreen was gone and Android rebuilt the `locksettings.db` file itself.

I am using [TWRP recovery](https://twrp.me/) on a Samsung Galaxy S4.

Comment: `adb shell settings put secure lockscreen.disabled 1`

Comment: Does this require a rooted device or anything?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to explore [exilit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22145394/1099884) answer. From the source, we finally get into this:

```
mChooseLockSettingsHelper.utils().clearLock(false);
mChooseLockSettingsHelper.utils().setLockScreenDisabled(disabled);
```

The utils is the `com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils` object and we can somehow get it by reflection.
Here is the code:

```
    try{
            Class lockPatternUtilsCls = Class.forName("com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils");
            Constructor lockPatternUtilsConstructor = 
                lockPatternUtilsCls.getConstructor(new Class[]{Context.class});
            Object lockPatternUtils = lockPatternUtilsConstructor.newInstance(MyActivity.this);

            Method clearLockMethod = lockPatternUtils.getClass().getMethod("clearLock", boolean.class);
            Method setLockScreenDisabledMethod = lockPatternUtils.getClass().getMethod("setLockScreenDisabled", boolean.class);

            clearLockMethod.invoke(lockPatternUtils, false);
            setLockScreenDisabledMethod.invoke(lockPatternUtils, true);                 
            Log.d(TAG, "set lock screen to NONE SUC");
    }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG, "set lock screen to NONE failed", e);
    }
```

Well my testing app is with signed with platform key and a system app. I think it will be a must.

Updated:
Noticed that the methods arguments are changed on Android 6.

Answer (score 1):

I have acheived in root tablet,

Below is my full procedure

adb push sqlite3 /sdcard/sqlite3

adb shell

su

mount -o remount,rw /system

cp /sdcard/sqlite3 /system/xbin/sqlite3

chmod 755 /system/xbin/sqlite3

mount -o remount,ro /system

adb shell sqlite3 /data/system/locksettings.db

UPDATE locksettings SET value = '1' WHERE name = 'lockscreen.disabled'

You can download the file from http://www.digitechhub.com/sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

On rooted nexus 5,
In terminal via twrp recovery I simply
rm /data/system/locksettings.db
and reboot

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).