# How to set password for Password lock or PIN lock programmatically?

Tags: android

I know Screen Lock inclue None, Swipe,Pattern,Password and PIN.

I have read the docment [How can i set up screen lock with a password programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724428/how-can-i-set-up-screen-lock-with-a-password-programmatically)

I don't know what kind of lock type the following code apply to.

I have test the following code using different phones, it seems that sometimes the code apply to Password lock, and sometimes the code apply to PIN lock, I don't know why?

```
DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager =(DevicePolicyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
ComponentName demoDeviceAdmin =new ComponentName(this, MyAdmin.class);

devicePolicyManager.setPasswordQuality(demoDeviceAdmin,DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_UNSPECIFIED);
devicePolicyManager.setPasswordMinimumLength(demoDeviceAdmin, 5);

boolean result = devicePolicyManager.resetPassword("123456", DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);

Toast.makeText(this, "button_lock_password_device..."+result,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the **value** you pass as the first parameter in `devicePolicyManager.resetPassword()`, the Lock will either ask for  PIN or Password.

```
// Screen Lock will act as PIN.
devicePolicyManager.resetPassword("123456", DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);

// Screen Lock will act as Password.
devicePolicyManager.resetPassword("123abc", DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
```

So for alphanumeric = password

```
   numbers = pin
```

Hope it helps!!!