# Set pass code for an android application in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, passwords

I am working on a application , it is having an pass code screen with 4 digits. How to set pass code like that screen and when I open the app I need to show the pass code screen in order to open the application.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to google out something before you ask any question..any way this may help you JUST START your THOUGHT.

[How can i set up screen lock with a password programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724428/how-can-i-set-up-screen-lock-with-a-password-programmatically)