# How to show system password option if Biometric authentication failed?

Tags: android, android-biometric-prompt

I have added Biometric Prompt in my Android app. So on app start, I am able to show prompt and if success is able to redirect user on the Dashboard screen. In case user failed I want to show System password as a secondary option to authenticate. How to do that with Biometric Prompt?

```
mBiometricManager = new BiometricManager.BiometricBuilder(FingerprintActivity.this)
                .setTitle(getString(R.string.biometric_title))
                .setSubtitle(getString(R.string.biometric_subtitle))
                .setDescription(getString(R.string.biometric_description))        
                .setNegativeButtonText(getString(R.string.biometric_negative_button_text))
                .build();

 mBiometricManager.authenticate(FingerprintActivity.this);
```

Answer (score 1):

on your biometric prompt add this

```
.setDeviceCredentialAllowed(true)
```

But check phone has a password/passcode setup  with:

```
android.app.KeyguardManager.isDeviceSecure()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle by extending `BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback`,  there are two main methods for handling fail state. `onAuthenticationError` and `onAuthenticationFailed`

**onAuthenticationFailed**

When the fingerprint doesn’t match with any of the fingerprints registered on the device, then this callback will be triggered.

**onAuthenticationError**

When an unrecoverable error has been encountered and the authentication process has completed without success, then this callback will be triggered. The callback is provided with an error code to identify the cause of the error

You can use [Device administration API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) for showing system password in the case of Biometic auth fail.

Comment: Can you please provide some link with example? Because I cannot find anything? And one more thing is that Device Administration API deprecated from Android P.

Comment: pls try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9724428/how-can-i-set-up-screen-lock-with-a-password-programmatically

Comment: Tried this, but it asked me to set Password, whereas password is already set. Instead what I want is, if biometric authentication failed, will show user a password field so that he can enter system password and redirect to Dashboard.